# ViewState Encryption doesn't work with mixed algorithms

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I have a client who wants to turn on ViewState encryption in an ASP.NET Web Forms application. They are not able to use the default algorithms because of FIPS compliance. The initial request from the client was to use 3DES/AES as follows, which I added to the web.config file:

```
<machineKey validationKey="..." decryptionKey="..." validation="3DES" decryption="AES" />
```

Putting in this configuration caused the application to stop working with the following error:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to validate data.]
System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData) +1090
System.Web.UI.Page.EncryptString(String s, Purpose purpose) +150
[...]
```

By switching *both* keys to 3DES, I was able to get the system working.

Why does the system fail when the two different algorithms are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure why that's failing - perhaps some error with the length of the key provided?  The inner exception should be able to tell you more if there's one present.

Regardless, you should be aware that 3DES is being phased out by NIST and that ASP.NET does not use 3DES in a FIPS-compliant fashion. (Reference: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-67-Rev1/SP-800-67-Rev1.pdf. See in particular the foreword, which states that we're in a transitional period for customers to move off of 3DES and on to AES. Also see Section 3.5; ASP.NET does not limit the number of invocations of the block cipher algorithm, so our particular usage of this algorithm makes it non-FIPS-compliant.)

The best course of action would be to use AES for encryption / decryption and HMACSHA256 for validation.  This combination is FIPS-compliant and provides better security than 3DES / SHA1 (which is what was being used earlier).  To do this, set:

```
<machineKey validation="HMACSHA256" validationKey="256 bits worth of hex digits (64 hex chars)" decryption="AES" decryptionKey="256 bits worth of hex digits (64 hex chars)" />
```

Then also set `<pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />` in Web.config to tell ASP.NET to use view state encryption using the algorithms you just provided in the `<machineKey>` element.

Comment: Levi, thanks very much for the info. I'm not too familiar with the encryption world so this is very helpful. The document you linked *does* mention 3DES in the "Symmetric Encryption" section - #2 under AES (assuming TDEA and 3DES are synonymous.) Can you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Also, to answer your question I don't *think* it was the keys involved. I used this page: http://www.a2zmenu.com/utility/Machine-Key-Generator.aspx to generate keys and tried multiple different keys.

Comment: Wow, that was absolutely the wrong thing for me to write. :)
I've updated that paragraph with what I was trying to say: the way that ASP.NET uses it makes it non-FIPS-compliant.

Comment: Thanks for much for all the information! Great answer Levi. I haven't actually solved the question of why my initial combination causes an error but your suggestion was preferred by the customer anyway.